# Ignoring Specific Patterns Between Delimiters When Comparing Text Files in Core Java

Tags: java, xml, file, selenium-webdriver, underscore-java

I'm working with two text files, File1.txt and File2.txt, and comparing them using Core Java. While doing so, I need to disregard certain values in the comparison.

Specifically, any value that falls between the strings XYZ and ZYX should be excluded from the comparison.

Here's a brief example of the contents of the two files:

**File1.txt**

```
-----------------------------
XYZ12345ZYX
abcddd......
I am going to Delhi .............
Mumbai isgoodXYZ6789ZYX
```

**File2.txt**

```
----------------------------
XYZ111111ZYX
abcddd......
I am going to Delhi .............
Mumbai isgoodXYZ00000ZYX
```

From the example:

- The values 12345 in File1.txt and 111111 in File2.txt should be ignored.
- The values 6789 in File1.txt and 00000 in File2.txt should also be ignored.

I'm curious to know if anyone is familiar with a widely-recognized method, algorithm, or logic to address this challenge. Any experiences or suggestions?

Comment: you could: read the line of the string, use regex replaceAll() to get a version of the string without the numbers that are enclosed by XYZ ZYX, or actually just remove XYZ...ZYX all together

Comment: What has xml todo with this question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below uses the java.nio.file and java.util.regex packages. It reads the files line by line and utilizes a regex pattern to identify and replace the specific patterns ("XYZ...ZYX") with a constant placeholder ("XYZIGNOREZYX").

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class FileComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path file1Path = Paths.get("File1.txt");
        Path file2Path = Paths.get("File2.txt");

        // Use process method below to remove random text 
        // between your static bounded text 
        List<String> file1Lines = processFile(file1Path);
        List<String> file2Lines = processFile(file2Path);

        // Now you can compare file1Lines and file2Lines

    }

    // This method will identify pattern and replace the random text
    // identified by regex with a constant value
    private static List<String> processFile(Path filePath) throws IOException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("XYZ.*?ZYX");
        return Files.lines(filePath)
            .map(line -> {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                return matcher.replaceAll("XYZIGNOREZYX");
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The regex pattern `.*?` matches any number of any characters, but as few as possible to still make the match (this is called [non-greedy matching](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-development/core-java/util/regex/greedy-and-non-greedy-reg-ex-matching/#:%7E:text=A%20greedy%20regular%20expression%20is,matches%20the%20pattern%20is%20returned.) - use this link to learn more).

This is necessary to correctly handle lines that contain multiple "XYZ...ZYX" patterns.

The replaceAll method replaces all matches of the regex with "XYZIGNOREZYX"